# SQL equivalent of mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

What is the equivalent of the below in SQL?

PHP function for MySQL:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($POST['password']);
```

Comment: Use parameters with PDO.

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: There is no in-sql equivalent.

Comment: This question makes no sense. What do you mean?

Comment: In order for there to be an in-SQL equivilant you would need to still submit the string to MySQL, at which point any damage would already be being done.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping is done to prepare a SQL statement correctly. There is no equivalent in MySQL because by the time it hits that layer it *should* have been escaped in the first place.

Using `mysqli_real_escape_string` is also a sign you're doing something incorrectly as you should be using the `bind_param` method instead of this kind of super low-level call.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is **not** 'doing something incorrectly'. Prepared Statements are one approach to securing SQL, but they are not a silver bullet. Prepared statements carry a performance overhead in many uses, and do not support some useful syntax variations. `mysqli_real_eascape_string` is a valid method of escaping SQL inputs. The important thing is to ensure the security of your SQL. Insisting that prepared statements is the only 'correct' way is just lazy thinking.

Comment: @Mike Amen! `*_real_escape_string` works just fine *if applied correctly!*

Comment: The number of disastrously bad code examples I've seen here suggest that most people don't understand how to use any of the `escape_string` functions correctly or, more importantly, consistently. What's the performance overhead of placeholders? Is it even measurable? If so, why is PHP one of the few languages that makes a habit of calling low-level escaping functions? If PDO has a performance problem, then it should be fixed. Encouraging people to escape their own data without placeholders is not helping.